# What elliptic curves are used by Tezos?

Tags: account, cryptography

Do tz1, tz2, tz3 addresses correspond to the different elliptic curves used by Tezos?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, Tezos supports three types of keys associated with 3 kinds of [elliptic curves](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic-curve_cryptography)

- [tz1](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/mainnet/src/lib_crypto/ed25519.ml#L40) for [Ed25519](https://ed25519.cr.yp.to/) keys,
- [tz2](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/mainnet/src/lib_crypto/secp256k1.ml#L39) for [Secp256k1](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Secp256k1) keys (same as Bitcoin/Ethereum)
- [tz3](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/mainnet/src/lib_crypto/p256.ml#L40) for [NIST P256](https://csrc.nist.gov/csrc/media/events/workshop-on-elliptic-curve-cryptography-standards/documents/papers/session6-adalier-mehmet.pdf) keys which may have led to some amount of [controversy](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/52983/why-is-there-the-option-to-use-nist-p-256-in-gnupg) but is one of the most used elliptic curve, including native support in some mobile devices like the [iphone](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/projects/cryptographic-module-validation-program/documents/security-policies/140sp3148.pdf)

Source:

http://www.ocamlpro.com/2018/11/21/an-introduction-to-tezos-rpcs-signing-operations/